# crash app on MP4 video clip merging

Tags: android, video, mp4, mp4parser

I am using MP4Parser to to combine two MP4 video clips but I got exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No box object found for ftyp
            at com.coremedia.iso.PropertyBoxParserImpl$FourCcToBox.invoke(PropertyBoxParserImpl.java:187)
            at com.coremedia.iso.PropertyBoxParserImpl.createBox(PropertyBoxParserImpl.java:90)
            at com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:87)
            at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.parse(IsoFile.java:85)
            at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.<init>(IsoFile.java:54)
            at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:32)
            at com.apps.my.activity.CreateVideo.MergeVideos(CreateVideo.java:250)
            at com.apps.my.activity.CreateVideo$1.onClick(CreateVideo.java:113)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have search on internet and see different links. I found that I should add AspectJ and for this I did it by downloading and adding AspectJ Weaving plugin in the app. but it is still the issue.
Can anyone help me. **I am using Android Studio for development**

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: i face same error, any one find solutions ?